# What is the difference between .exe file generated from c program compilation and .exe file generated from vb program compilation

Tags: c, vb.net, exe, platform-independent

what is difference between .exe file generated from c program compilation  and .exe file  generated from vb program compilation.
Which .exe file is platform independent as per ( as long as the platform is .NET)?

Comment: It is compiled in the form of intermediate language IL in VB.NET. `.c` is written to exe file that tones and machine language native. However, the source of the c as `.cpp`(C++) is output as IL If a program is pure option(`/clr:pure`).

Comment: VB.NET handles platform independence pretty well.  But of course can never hide the target implementation.  You are not going to have much use for a console mode app on an XBox or a Safari plugin or a phone.  Portability concerns is a quaint relic from the days of the Unix wars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C program file mostly compiles to native machine code and is platform specific. However, VB.NET compiles to .NET MSIL code, which can then run on a .NET Virtual Machine.

That being said, you can write your own compiler for C that compiles to MSIL or look at C++/CLR.

Comment: Also, VB.NET requires .Net Framework to be installed on the client machine. The .Net Framework currently ships with many recent windows.

Comment: Yeah that's true @EmmadKareem - for example, Java is platform independent but still requires you to have JVM installed to run it. That's the cost of being platform independent.

Comment: And just in case @DhavalShah meant C# instead of C, C# compiles the same as VB -- To .Net MSIL.